# Is it possible to express it with all the products of the symbolized expression developed for sympy?

Tags: python, math, sympy, symbolic-math

I used sympy to express the trace of results of matrix multiplications in a symbolic way. The result comes out as below, is it possible to get the result in a form where the product is fully expanded?

[Result of the trace](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0wFFx.png)

Comment: Please do not use images to show text. Instead, include your trace as text in the post itself.

Answer (score 0):

Use `expand`:

```py
>>> expr = (x + y)*(x + 1); expr.expand()
x**2 + x*y + x + y'
```